# 2001 BIONICLE Trading Card #255?

Tags: bionicle

This is probably a long shot, but does anyone have or know where to find a picture of the 2001 BIONICLE trading card #255? It's presumably one of the illustrated story cards, and likely features a Muaka or maybe a Tarakava.

Unfortunately BIONICLEsector01 does not have a picture of this card, nor have I been able to find one with a Google search.

[image]

Any other information about the card, like proof it does not actually exist, would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bioniclelego/comments/gurnxq/bionicle_quest_for_the_masks_tcg_rahi_challenge/), I was able to find [this Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tQAx78LnOMubH0vHKT_KOyfHQ9BKiMAk) which had scans of the base game, the Rahi Challenge expansion pack (including the front and back of card #255), and the Bohrok Swarm standalone game. The drive has been stable for a year as of writing (June 2021), but you may wish to archive its contents in the event it becomes unavailable.

The scans appear to be higher quality than [the other archive](https://brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=168918&n=0) I found on Brickshelf which did not have card #255.

[image: 255 side A]

[image: 255 side B]